# JDBC Why is it returning me all available tables?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have quite a complex bit of code so I can't show it all, but this part is very simple.

I have a `SELECT * FROM myTable` which returns a result set to this method which should print it, `toUse` is the name of the passed result set to this method:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = (ResultSetMetaData) toUse.getMetaData();      

          System.out.println("");

          int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

          for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            System.out.print(columnName);
          }
          System.out.println("");

          while (toUse.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
              if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
              String columnValue = toUse.getString(i);
              System.out.print(columnValue);
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
```

Rather than printing out the table I selected from, it is instead excuting a `SHOW TABLES;` command?

Edit:

I think it has something to do with this running earlier on:

```
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
        results = meta.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});

        while (results.next()) {

          String tableName = results.getString("TABLE_NAME");
          if(tableName.equals(parameters)){
              return true;
          }

        }
    results.close();
    return false;
```

Comment: ResultSetMetaData returns me all available (depends of user access in DB) databases tables too,

Comment: Can you show the query and how you are generating the `toUse` field?

Comment: Not really, its a whole load of jumping around the code going on. But I'm sure the confliction is caused by this bit of code which runs earlier - see main edit

Comment: @Eric I misread your question, it seems that you managed to pass the result set of your second snippet to the first one as `toUse`. You should really refactor if this turns out to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've somehow got a broken jdbc driver, there should be no problem between calling .getMetaData() on a Connection before calling .getMetaData() on a ResultSet. You've most likely accidentally altered the value of toUse. One way to validate that you haven't accidentally changed its value is to make your local variable final.

P.S. Instead of this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
    if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
    String columnValue = toUse.getString(i);
    System.out.print(columnValue);
}
```

Do this:

```
String delimiter = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
    String columnValue = toUse.getString(i);
    System.out.print(delimiter);
    System.out.print(columnValue);
    delimiter = ",  ";
}
```

No need for a branch condition inside of your loop.